# Which material Should I use to create bottom sheet in iOS

Tags: ios, material-design

This question is about my understanding of what kind of material design I should use so that I can implement something below in iOS. Please find a image of what we have in Android, 
https://www.filemail.com/d/jezaeiintbbjihn

We call our location API every 10 secs which moves the icon. When the user clicks on the icon it opens  a bottom drawer. It's refreshed every 10 seconds and shows data from the API until we close that drawer.

In iOS, what kind of material design shall I consider for this?

The example API out put we have:

```
{"user_id":"xxxxx-036e-45ea-abac-4d84511e1654","device_id":"xxxxx","timestamp":"2019-10-26 09:22:25","location":"23.736756666666665;90.41241999999998","lsb":0,"speed":"25.2","heading":108.36,"engine":1,"door":0,"fuel":"0.00","temperature":"0","ins_timestamp":"2019-10-26 09:22:31"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google themselves has been open-sourcing the components they’ve used to build Material Design-powered apps on iOS. If you wish to have the almost same feel that you have in your android application you can try using the google's open sourced material components for iOS. You can refer the link to know more.

https://material.io/develop/ios/

For your need, you can use bottomsheet material component for iOS provided by material.io.

https://material.io/develop/ios/components/bottom-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following also:

https://github.com/amr-abdelfattah/iOS-OptionMenu

I have built it based on:
https://material.io/develop/ios/components/bottom-sheet/

It’s for easily and flexible creation of Material Bottom Sheet.